# I have 2 database queries and wanted to make them as one

Tags: mysql

I have the following problem:
I have 2 database queries and wanted to make them as one.

```
SELECT SUM(verguetung_lead) FROM einkaeufe WHERE bearbeitet_wann >= '$zaehl_heute_von' AND bearbeitet_wann <= '$zaehl_heute_bis'
SELECT SUM(verguetung_lead) FROM einkaeufe WHERE bearbeitet_wann >= '$zaehl_gestern_von' AND bearbeitet_wann <= '$zaehl_gestern_bis'
```

Table `einkaeufe`

```
bearbeitet_wann | verguetung_lead
----------------+----------------
1536937398      | 99.00
1536803939      | 10.00
```

```
SELECT
SUM(if(bearbeitet_wann >= '1536962460',bearbeitet_wann <= '1537048740',verguetung_lead)) AS einkaeufe_verguetet_heute_daten,
SUM(if(bearbeitet_wann >= '1536876060',bearbeitet_wann <= '1536962340',verguetung_lead)) AS einkaeufe_verguetet_gestern_daten,
SUM(if(bearbeitet_wann >= '1536444060',bearbeitet_wann <= '1537135140',verguetung_lead)) AS einkaeufe_verguetet_woche_daten
FROM einkaeufe
```

ouput

```
[einkaeufe_verguetet_heute_daten] => 109.00 [einkaeufe_verguetet_gestern_daten] => 11.00 [einkaeufe_verguetet_woche_daten] => 2.00 )
```

First line time `2018-09-14T15:03:18+00:00`

Second line time `2018-09-13T01:58:59+00:00`

Somehow the numbers are not right

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `IF` properly, the second parameter is the "value if true" and the third the "value if false" (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)). You can also simplify your `SELECT` by using [`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between). Try this:

```
SELECT
SUM(if(bearbeitet_wann between 1536962460 and 1537048740,verguetung_lead, 0)) AS einkaeufe_verguetet_heute_daten,
SUM(if(bearbeitet_wann between 1536876060 and 1536962340,verguetung_lead, 0)) AS einkaeufe_verguetet_gestern_daten,
SUM(if(bearbeitet_wann between 1536444060 and 1537135140,verguetung_lead, 0)) AS einkaeufe_verguetet_woche_daten
FROM einkaeufe
```

Output:

```
einkaeufe_verguetet_heute_daten     einkaeufe_verguetet_gestern_daten   einkaeufe_verguetet_woche_daten
0,00                                99,00                               109,00
```

Comment: super problem is >= <= for timestamp still have to go in

Comment: that's what `between` does, `a between b and c` is equivalent to `a >= b and a <= c`

Comment: Or am I not understanding what you are saying?

Comment: is now great for me was my timestamp query weeksday date ("w", time ()) now date ("N", time ()) 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
$datetime_start = date("Y-m-d");
SELECT
SUM(if(lastupdate between Like '%".$datetime_start."%',verguetung, 0)) AS einkaeufe_verguetet_heute_daten,
FROM einkaeufe
```

should spend the load update only from today